# JS. Как обратиться к свойству объекта во время его объявления

Tags: javascript

Объявляю в скрипте объект с настройками, и получается, что мне нужно обратится во время объявления к свойству в этом же объекте.

```
const settings = {
theme_name: 'theme',
input: {
    styles: [
        this.theme_name + '/dev/styles/main.scss',
        this.theme_name + '/lib/styles/**/*.scss'
    ],
...
```

Здесь на месте `this.theme_name` по логике должна встать строка `theme_name`, но вместо этого `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ишь какой хитрый. Контекст ( читай `this` ) определяется на момент вызова/создания. У тебя при инициализации объекта контекст ссылается на глобальный, где нет никакого `theme_name`

Можно, если очень хочется использовать классы для этого

```
class Settings {
    constructor() {
        this.theme_name = 'theme';
        this.input = {
            styles: [
                this.theme_name + '/dev/styles/main.scss',
                this.theme_name + '/lib/styles/**/*.scss'
            ]
        }
    }
}

const settings = new Settings();
console.log(settings);
```

Ну или просто хранить значение в переменной

```
const theme_name = 'theme';
const settings = {
    theme_name,
    input: {
        styles: [
            theme_name + '/dev/styles/main.scss',
            theme_name + '/lib/styles/**/*.scss'
        ],
    }
}
```

Еще как вариант использовать геттер

```
const settings = {
    theme_name: 'theme',
    get input() {
        return {styles: [
            this.theme_name + '/dev/styles/main.scss',
            this.theme_name + '/lib/styles/**/*.scss'
        ]};
    }
}
```

Comment: С геттером надо быть аккуратнее. При каждом обращении к settings.input будет создан новый объект.